# Java's PipedReader / PipedWriter equivalents in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, stream

I have defined a Pipe class in Java, making use of `PipedReader` and `PipedWriter`. I am now trying to port this same class to C#. Is it possible to accomplish the same as shown in the following code in C#?

```
public final class Pipe {
    private final PipedReader pipedReader = new PipedReader();
    private final PipedWriter pipedWriter = new PipedWriter();

    public Pipe() {
        pipedWriter.connect(pipedReader);
    }

        ...
}
```

I am guessing what I'll want to use in C# for `PipedReader` and `PipedWriter` will be `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`?

Is there something like a `connect()` method?

### Edit

So, my goal is to implement a (little) Pipe&Filter framework.
My idea would be to create a Pipe class and Filter classes, so that when I need to implement some system using a Pipe&Filter architecture style, I'll code it against this little framework I am using.
Each filter would run on its own thread.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please give a more high-level description of what you're trying to accomplish, rather than explaining it in Java terms? Maybe there's a completely different way to do it in .NET.

Comment: Are you just trying to do IPC?  You might be interested in using the named or anonymous pipes defined in the [`System.IO.Pipes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.aspx) namespace (note: .NET 3.5 and above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but there is a tutorial on using .Net pipes [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/dotnet-35-adds-named-pipes-support). This will only work with .Net 3.5+.

**EDIT:**

There are examples on MSDN about using anonymous pipes. See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546102.aspx).

Comment: I've already read that. I am looking for unnamed pipes, though.

Comment: Edited to include a link to anonymous pipes examples on MSDN.

Comment: Isn't there anything *simpler*? I am not looking for ipc, just a way (probably with something like streams) that'd allow me to pass data sequentially across threads (preferably in a thread-safe way).

Comment: I don't know of anything built into .Net. You'll probably have to write your own. I believe the pipedreader/writer in Java is for working with characters rather than bytes. There is no direct equivalent that I'm aware of in .Net. There is a StringReader class and a StreamReader class (this works with bytes, but does allow other streams to be passed into the constructor).

Comment: Actually the stream reader class does allow you to read characters. The Read method has an override to return chars (the int32 value of the character).