# Concurrent XmlReader and XmlWriter

Tags: c#, xml, multithreading

I have a system that creates some `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter` instances, and **passes them to clients**, so that the clients can write and read XML.

Sometimes, multiple threads access the system:

1. Thread 1 gets an `XmlWriter` instance and starts writing
2. Thread 2 gets an `XmlReader` instance that represents the same XML document, and starts reading.

Obviously, sometimes the reader starts reading before the writer has completed writing, which causes an exception to be thrown in the reader:

> System.Xml.XmlException : Root element is missing.

That's not particularly surprising, but is there any way to make this system thread-safe?

- Is it possible to make the reader read *while* the writer writes? I tried using a `MemoryStream` as the underlying data store, but that didn't seem to work.
- Is it possible to make the reader *wait until* the writer has completed writing?
- Is it possible to detect that the writer is still writing?

Any of the above approaches would, I believe, solve my problem. It's not required that writing and reading happens simultaneously. Actually, I would be perfectly happy if I could simply tell the client requesting the `XmlReader` that the reader isn't ready yet, and it must try again later. However, that requires that there's a way to detect that the writer is still writing.

I have full control over the code that creates the `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter` instances, but I can't change the public API. I can use a `string`, a `StringBuilder`, a `MemoryStream`, or any other in-memory object that will get the job done, as underlying storage, and I can use any derived class of `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter`.

Is there any way to make this system thread-safe?

Comment: you need to create a checkout/checkin mechanism.

Comment: You could probably create your own stream that would serve as a provider to your XML reader / writer, and it will block on read opperation until it knows that all writes are completed.  Once write(s) occured, unblock read and proceed happily.  You can probably still use MemoryStream as backing to  your custom stream.

Comment: When you say "clients" are you talking multiple processes? (please tell me no).

Comment: @PeterRitchie No, just other objects in the same process (but on different threads).

Comment: @LB2: Blocking on the stream level may be insufficient, as the stream has no idea when an operation is actually complete.

Comment: Phew, a RWL sounds exactly what you need.

Comment: @AdamRobinson Based on _"Is it possible to make the reader wait until the writer has completed writing?"_ it sounds like content is small, so one can wait until `XmlWriter` is closed and detect it by it closing underlying stream, which would serve as signal to unblock reading stream. But I agree with later comment that RWL is probably what OP is really looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to create custom classes that derive from `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter`. You can add a common synchronization object to them and use something like a `ReadWriterLockSlim` to coordinate reading and writing. You would have to determine in the writer class what you mean when you say it's "done" (disposed? done writing a single node even if it's not completely done? etc.)

You could then just make the methods in the reader block until writing is not in progress.

Comment: Thank you, this solution was all I needed. In fact, I could get by with only creating a class deriving from `XmlWriter`, which included a callback when it was being disposed of. Until the callback occurs, I simply tell the readers that the document isn't ready yet, and then when the callback occurs, the document becomes available.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is a stream that lets one thread write while the other reads. The .NET Framework doesn't supply such a thing. You could potentially do it with a named pipe, but I found that cumbersome. So I wrote what I called a `ProducerConsumerStream`. It's just a circular queue wrapped up in a `Stream` interface. See [Building a new type of stream](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=852) for a description and full source.

To use it with `XmlWriter` and `XmlReader`, you'd do something like this:

```
const int BufferSize = 1024 * 1024;  // megabyte stream buffer

var pcStream = new ProducerConsumerStream(BufferSize);

// start producer thread, passing it the stream
// start consumer thread, passing it the stream

// Destroy the stream when the producer and consumer are done
```

The producer thread would create an `XmlWriter` that writes to the stream:

```
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(pcStream, writerSettings))
{
    // write xml here
}

// when you're done writing XML, call CompleteAdding on the stream.
// This will let the reader know when the stream is ended.
pcStream.CompleteAdding();
```

The reader thread is similar:

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(pcStream, readerSettings))
{
    // read XML here
}
```

Be sure that in your writer settings you set `CloseOutput = false`, and in the reader settings set `CloseInput = false`. Otherwise the stream could be disposed prematurely.

The key here is that `ProducerConsumerStream.Read` blocks until it can read data. Unless the end of stream has been signaled by calling `CompleteAdding`.

Understand, this is an in-memory structure. If you want to persist the XML as well, you'll have to do that some other way. Although I suppose you could derive from `ProducerConsumerStream` and override the `Write` method so that it outputs to file as well as copying things to the internal buffer.

Comment: This looks like the correct general-purpose solution to this sort of problem (so +1). I was hoping that this was already built into the BCL, and that I was just overlooking something obvious, but that seems not to be the case. However, as this suggested solution is rather complex, and I could manage with a simpler solution, I've selected another answer as 'the' answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need something similar to the PipedReader/PipedWriter in Java. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedReader.html. It looks like .NET doesn't have anything like it: [Java's PipedReader / PipedWriter equivalents in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528105/javas-pipedreader-pipedwriter-equivalents-in-c).

You could do the same thing as in Java by implementing your own System.IO.TextWriter and System.IO.TextReader by using this Java code as a base:

http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/io/PipedReader.java/?v=source

http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/io/PipedWriter.java/?v=source

Comment: This looks like the correct general-purpose solution to this sort of problem (so +1). I was hoping that this was already built into the BCL, and that I was just overlooking something obvious, but that seems not to be the case. However, as this suggested solution is rather complex, and I could manage with a simpler solution, I've selected another answer as 'the' answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to make the reader *wait until* the writer has completed writing?

Yes with a [hybrid thread synchronization construct](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735667454), e.g. [ManualResetEventSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim.aspx), as follows:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var readOperation = new ManualResetEventSlim();
        var stream = new MemoryStream();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    "Thread {0} is writing...", 
                    Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                Thread.Sleep(3000);

                CreateXmlDocument(writer);
            }
            stream.Position = 0;
            readOperation.Set();
        });

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            readOperation.Wait();
            using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
                while (reader.Read())
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "Thread {0} is reading...", 
                        Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        });

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
Thread 7 is writing...
Thread 11 is reading...
Thread 11 is reading...
Thread 11 is reading...
Thread 11 is reading...
Thread 11 is reading...
Thread 11 is reading...
Thread 11 is reading...
Thread 11 is reading...
Thread 11 is reading...
Thread 11 is reading...
Thread 11 is reading...
Thread 11 is reading...
Thread 11 is reading...
Thread 11 is reading...
```

---

The `CreateXmlDocument` function (although it's not very interesting) is defined as:

```
private static void CreateXmlDocument(XmlWriter writer)
{
    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    writer.WriteStartElement("Product");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("ID", "001");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("Name", "Soap");
    writer.WriteElementString("Price", "10.00");
    writer.WriteStartElement("OtherDetails");
    writer.WriteElementString("BrandName", "X Soap");
    writer.WriteElementString("Manufacturer", "X Company");
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndDocument();
}
```

Comment: This solution relies on synchronization at the client. However, I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require the clients to be synchronized, as the writer and reader may have no knowledge of each other.

Comment: Oh, I see... I put emphasis on the fact that you have full control over the code that creates the `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter` instances.

Answer (score 0):

A simple idea is to create a (possibly static) dictionary of documents that are currently being written.  While that document is in that dictionary read requests are either blocked or rejected.

Answer (score -2):

Good idea it is to create a copy of XML file in a lock that affected on a XMLWriter too.

Writer code:

```
lock(_WriteLock)
     _MyXmlWriter.Flush();
```

Reader code:

```
lock(_WriteLock)
     File.Copy(myXMLFilePath, tempXMLFilePath);
_MyXMLReader = new XMLReader(tempXMLFilePath);
```

Comment: why copy if you're locking the file?